# Build only affected modules in Jenkins / Maven

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

We are using Git, Jenkins and Artifactory as CI/CD pipeline.
We have a large code base and each time the full build takes a lot of time to process. For example, we have a aggregated pom project containing 100+ modules. The parent `pom.xml` file looks like the following:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module-1</module>
        <module>module-2</module>
        <module>module-n</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

We use this structure because some modules depend on some others. Also, we want to centralize the common dependencies, dependenciesManagement & pluginManagement in this parent pom file instead of maintaining 100+ pom files per module.

Because changes may not happen on every modules, we want to speed up the build process by only building the affected modules since last successful build. This can be done by maven.

Example: `mvn clean install -pl module1,module2,module3 -amd -am`

It is easy if the developer knows what modules has been changed. If not, some maven plugin can help the developer to detect the uncommitted changes compared with git repository. Or some people may do `mvn install -amd -pl $(git status | grep -E "modified:|deleted:|added:" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d"/")`

But these solutions do not fit to our Jenkins pipeline. The Jenkins server always pull the latest version of the project from git and start the build. I don't know if Jenkins has the capability to detect what modules has been changed from git history and from its build history (any state info?). Besides, we are running multiple Jenkins slaves process. The build job is not always stick to the same machine workspace.

I searched one Jenkins plugin seem can solve my problem.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin

I tried to install a fresh latest version of Jenkins with this plugin but still unable to find the feature "Incremental build - only build changed modules".

Could somebody suggest some ways (by plugin or manuel scripting) to help to build only changed modules in Jenkins? I have been searching for many days and still could not find a workable solution. I would be very grateful if somebody could give me some insight or direction how we should do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by `takes a lot of time`? How many tests? How long do the tests run? How long is the real build time? Are you using parallelization (`mvn -T ..`) ? Why are you using an aggregated pom which mean no real mutli module build?

Comment: The full build takes 60 minutes excluding the unit test.
We used mvn -T, which can reduce the build time by 20-30%.
We use aggregated pom because some modules depends on each other (e.g. the data model module appears in dependency in some other modules). The other reason to use aggregated pom is to simplify the common default configuration (e.g. 3rd party lib dependency management version, scm setting) so that we don't have to update 100+ pom files each time.

Comment: Dependency Management can be done by a corporate parent and updating of parents etc. can be automized...scm settings is not really a reason cause this is done only once...using release plugin or other constructed things via Jenkins etc.

Comment: I agree with you that we don't have to structure the project like this. But we still need to tell Jenkins to build a recently changed project pom file automatically. How could we do that? We don't want to rely on the developer manually trigger the build process in Jenkins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question but if anyone is still looking for an answer,
I created a Jenkinsfile for a Multi Branch Pipeline which builds affected modules only for a maven multi-module project.

[Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/materia2021/jenkins-pipeline-maven-multi-module)

Comment: This is not working when i am raising a PR from the feature branch (this I created from the master branch) to my master branch, currentBuild.changeSets coming as empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the Multi Module Maven Release Plugin:

http://danielflower.github.io/multi-module-maven-release-plugin/index.html

But also consider: If your modules are usually built separately, why are they in one large multi-module project?

Comment: Mainly because we want to simplify some common configuration (e.g. 3rd party lib version, internal libraries/framework version) by the parent pom file, instead of maintaining 100+ pom files. All modules are actually belong to the same system. Each module build output are standalone jar application, serving different kinds of requests.

Comment: We use company-internal parent poms without putting everything into the same multi-module project. Having a parent-pom is independent of using multi-module.